# Update value in column based on column count in another table with mysql

Tags: mysql, database, doctrine-orm

As I couldn't find anything like this anywhere I'm guessing it's unlikely that it is possible. Just to be sure I figured I'd ask it here.

I have a database with 2 tables. Lets name them table A and B for now. I have a bunch of items in table B, of which each item has a many to one relation to an item in table A. Now in table A I have a field which should contain the count of how many items in table B relate to that particular item in A.
Example table A:

```
+----+------+---------+
| id | data | count_b |
+----+------+---------+
|  1 | blah |      2  |
|  2 | blah |      0  |
|  3 | blah |      1  |
+----+------+---------+
```

Example table B:

```
+----+------+--------+
| id | data | parent |
+----+------+--------+
|  1 | blah |      1 |
|  2 | blah |      1 |
|  3 | blah |      3 |
+----+------+--------+
```

Now I am wondering if there is a way to **automatically update the column count_b in table A everytime a row is inserted in to B**?

I'd like to achieve this using mysql only. My web application uses doctrine for database mappings, so if I could somehow define it as a relation there, it would be fine as well.

I tried explaining my question as clear as possible, if it's unclear just le me know in the comments. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do exactly what you want, you can create a [`TRIGGER`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html). To achieve a somewhat similar result, you could make a view on this table that contains an extra column containing this count.

I have a strong preference for the second option, because it prevents inserting redundant data into your database and also eliminates the need for a trigger, which is good if you realize that triggers can quickly turn into a performance and maintenance nightmare.

Comment: I'd also prefer using views myself, but I'm afraid it will become a mess when mapping them to objects with Doctrine. For my use I think the TRIGGER should work fine. As in the application I'm working on only the performance when returning data will matter, not the performance during insertion.

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm using Doctrine2 here, a nicer way to do this might be using a Lifecycle event instead of a TRIGGER. http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/events.html